# Search Control Outside Of The UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have `button` inside `user control`**AddPostUserControl**. I want when the click event of the `button` inside `user control` **AddPostUserControl** fire to find `asp:ListView` with ID **ShowPostsListView**. How can I do this ?

```
              <%--add post user control--%>
                <uc1:AddPostUserControl runat="server" id="AddPostUserControl" />

                <%--show posts--%>
                <asp:ListView ID="ShowPostsListView" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="thisPost">
                            <div class="thisPostAuthor">
                                <%# this.GetCurrentUser(Eval("User")) %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thisPostHeader">
                                <h3>
                                    <%# Eval("Title") %>
                                </h3>
                                <span class="postDateTime">
                                    <%# Eval("PostDate") %>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thisPostContent">
                                <p>
                                    <%# Eval("PostContent") %>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Why do you want that? A `UserControl` should be reusable and not  hardlinked with the page which contains it. Instead you should provide a custom event in your UserControl(which gets raised on button-click) that you can handle in this page. There you have the reference to the `ListView`. The page is the controller not the UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page
ListView lsv = page.FindControl("ShowPostsListView");
```